# Stone fireplace -- how to plaster over / mount TV?

Tags: repair, safety, mounting, fireplace, stone

we are moving into a new home an finding ourselves in a bit of a pickle re: living room/fireplace.

Based on the living room’s layout, *our tv will need to be mounted above our fireplace*. The problem is that our fireplace is stone.

[image]
click images to embiggen

[image]

[image]

Our home is an old Spanish style home so mounting a tv over the stone would cover that little shelf hole and I think make the whole aesthetic look too rustic/cabin-y.

So, I am hoping I can *plaster over the rock* and do something like this:

[image]

I got the design inspiration from the following pics because I think they are a good job of keeping the Spanish aesthetic

[image]

[image]

My questions come down to this:

1. Is it possible to do this OVER the current stone? (*Or would I be forced to demo?*)
2. How complicated of a job is this? (ie will I need to hire a contractor?)
3. Is plaster the right material?//is there another specific technique you’d recommend to do this?
4. If I do plaster over it, could I still mount a tv? if so would it even be remotely feasible to hide the cords and create a tunnel to feed them into

(PS Don’t be mean! I know it's sacrilege to cover the original stone, but I’m stuck with a living room layout that predated TVs… plus, the rock fireplace extends on the other side of the wall to the outside of the house so at least the original stone on that side would remain visible/untouched.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. You'll note that we work on a one question per post basis and that you've asked 4 questions. Also, note that Q2 is an opinion based question - for someone who works with stone & plaster or cement on a daily basis, this is probably an "eyes closed" job. For someone who has never worked with either, it'll be... more difficult.  We don't know your skills and/or willingness to learn, so we don't know if you'll need to hire. Q4 is totally separate from Q1/Q3 which _might_ be OK to ask together. That's a matter of planning.

Comment: Please [edit] this down to just one question then feel free to ask another question. Nobody will look down on you for doing so. Also, you can remove the "inspo" part - knowing what you're after is fine, knowing what inspired you to get there is "decorating and design" which is also off topic.

Comment: Also, it's your house, so design/decoration are _your_ decisions, not ours.

Comment: First there is one question(how to mount TV) then are 4 another ones. If want answer on  how to mount - best option is pole/arm from wooden celling - easy to mount, easy to lead cables looks great without any work on fireplace/chimney.

Comment: Best option is "not over the fireplace" which is one we've beaten to death, but people still suffer from the delusion that heat and smoke are *fine* for TV electronics, and that the pain in their neck from trying to watch a TV mounted that high is *perfecly normal and has nothing to do with it being mounted too high*

Comment: Please don't do that. Consider that you may actually come to appreciate the stone as part of the home's aesthetic, and also consider shifting your lifestyle to not center around a boob tube. I made similar mistakes with my first home that I came to regret. I my current home the living room does not host a television.